# redirect_to from jquery in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

While on a view, the user can use existing buttons to increase/decrease the quantity of the products in his cart.

When the cart has not products i want to navigate to another view. Since i am in jquery on the browser and already know where i want to go, I presume it doesnt make much sense to let the user proceed only to capture this situation later on on the controller/model.

Therefore, my question is how can i navigate to another view from within xxx.js.erb the rails-way?

UPDATE
Thanks Зелёный for guiging me to the right direction

What worked for me was: 
$(location).attr('href','<%=j store_index_url %>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks <Зелёный> for guiding me to the right direction.
I ended up using this:

```
 $(location).attr('href','<%=j store_index_url %>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect by Javascript try work aroud this example:

```
# xxx.js.erb
function() {
  var new_path = <%= @some_path_from_controller %>;
  document.location.href = new_path;
};
```

Read about [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location)

Comment: thanks you guided me to the right direction. +1  I used this    $(location).attr('href','<%=j store_index_url %>');

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot accept the answer because it didn't work for me. Navigation wasn't taking place. What worked for me is updated in my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Validation**

You'll have to do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".cart_button", function(){
   if( $(".cart_total").val() == "0" ){
      document.location.href = "/your/new/path";
   }else{
      //etc
   }
});
```

---

**Ajax**

A much better way to handle this will be with `ajax`

Specifically, you'll be sending requests to your `cart_controller` I presume. This means that if you want to manage the response in regards to the quantity of the cart, you'll be in a much stronger position if you use the built-in Rails `js` backend handling:

```
#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
   def update
       @cart = ....
       respond_to do |format|
          format.js
          format.html
       end
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to load the following:

```
#app/views/cart/update.js.erb
<% if @cart.total_quantity.zero? %>
  var new_path = "<%=j controller_path %">;
  document.location.href = new_path;
<% else %>
  // do something here
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks <Rich Peck>. this is what I am actually doing. Its only in the update,js,erb where I want to do the redirection. So it has to be done in Jquery.